# Disabling auto creating infrastructure with MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp, masstransit

I have a microservices project written on c#. It is using MassTransit library as easy way to use RabbitMQ. But this library are automatically creating all infra on RabbitMQ server (exchanges, queues and so on). But firm where i am working now has restrictions to auto creating infrastructure on server, they want to full control of rabbitmq server. And my question is can i disable auto creating infra from code? For example throw ex if there is no queue on the server and i have to create queue manually and after that try to start my app again?
Thank to everyone

Answer (score 1):

As stated by MassTransit creator [HERE](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2266), it is not possible.
And it is intentionally.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still true and this is not OK for those who want to have a separation between infrastructure code (for example, provisioned using Terraform) and application code.